# laravel create controller error In RouteRegistrar.php line 92: Attribute [recource] does not exist

Tags: laravel-5.8

When I want to create controller by command `php artisan make:cotroller CompayController --resource --model=Company`

and I got this error

> In RouteRegistrar.php line 92:  Attribute [recource] does not exist.

Comment: `php artisan make:controller CompayController --resource --model=Company` ....Please check the type mistake in controller

Comment: You have a lot of typos there, it may be the reason. `recource` instead of `resource`, `make:cotroller CompayController` instead of `make:controller CompanyController`

Answer (score 0):

For my experience, please check route before run the command.

It may cause by your route file. `Wrong init route`